# Clear Range from sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Visual basic below is the code to delete the data from sheet2 with the desired range it is not working and i am getting the error.

```
Sub Clear()

With ThisWorkbook
With .Worksheets("Sheet2")
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "": ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect ""
Sheet2.Unprotect "": ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect ""
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3:031").Clear
Sheet2.Protect "": ActiveWorkbook.Protect ""
ActiveSheet.Protect "": ActiveWorkbook.Protect ""
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?  What error are you getting?

Comment: When using ActiveSheet and ActiveWorkbook it will take the ones that are active, not the ones you put in your With.

Comment: Soulfire@ it gives me an error as Application-defined or object Defined error. Here "Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3:031").Clear"

Comment: David@: What can you suggest at this part can my code be amended.

Comment: It looks like you have a `0` zero rather than on O `O` in `Range("B3:031)"`.  Try changing the zero to the letter O.

Comment: It actually worked me i think i have to check up my eyes. Soulfire Rocks...!!!

Comment: VBA has a [Range.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223824%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and a [Range.ClearContents method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223828%28v=office.11%29.aspx). Probably not a good idea to attempt to redefine them.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear (:D) what the relationship between the Sheet2 Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) and the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is; nor even [ActiveWorkbook property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx) and the [ThisWorkbook property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215773%28v=office.11%29.aspx) but I'm of a mind that they are mutliple attempts at the same thing.

You need to take advantage of the parentage involed by your [With ... End With statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). Simply stating `With ThisWorkbook` does not infer anything unless you subsequently preface all children with a period (aka `.` or *full stop*). The `.` is what references parentage to the object in the With... End With statement.

```
Sub Protected_Clear()
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Unprotect ""
        With .Worksheets("Sheet2")
            .Unprotect ""
            .Range("B3:O31").Clear
            .Protect ""
        End With
        .Protect ""
        .Close savechanges:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

I've renamed your sub procedure `Protected_Clear` in order to avoid confusion and conflict with the VBA's own [Range.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223824%28v=office.11%29.aspx) function.